# Logging For Elastic Beanstalk and RDS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to setup logging for my **Elastic Beanstalk** (running a Django app) and **RDS instance**. I need to track the following:

1. All interactions with my site (GET, POST, etc.)
2. All interactions with the associated RDS instance (reads and writes)
3. Operating system logs
4. Firewall logs
5. Antimalware logs

This is to meet compliance requirements. **Which AWS services can I use to achieve this?** Thank you for your help and let me know if you need any other information.

Any suggestions help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. All interactions with my site (GET, POST, etc.)

You could setup [access logs on your ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html).

> 2. All interactions with the associated RDS instance (reads and writes)

RDS by itself provides a [lot of logging capabilities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.html). Thus you would have to review them and identify which you require. Also your application could provide its own logging of interactions with the RDS.

> 3. Operating system logs

EB already provides logging capabilities, but they are not streamed by default to `CloudWatch Logs`. If this would interest you, you would have to setup `CloudWatch Agent` for it as shown in the [EB docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html#AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.prereqs).

> 4 and 5: Firewall and Antimalware logs

Not sure which firewall and antimalware logs. If you have setup firewall on the instances and have setup some antimalware monitoring tool, then you can also use `CloudWatch Agent` from step 3 to also stream these logs to `CloudWatch Logs`.

> Other possible logs

For general monitoring of traffic in your VPC, e.g. from your instances to ALB, you can also setup [VPC Flow Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html).

To monitor and log changes to the configuration of your EB environment you can enable [AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html).

There are also other possibilities, but I'm not sure if its sense to list them all.

Comment: Thank you so much Marcin!! Will give this a shot and get back.

Comment: @NGI No problem :-)

Comment: I had a quick question: for 1, I was able to setup the access logging. However, I don't want to store these in S3 forever. Is there some way to automatically pipe old logs into Glacier? I though s3 had some setting for it but I cant find it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @NGI Yes. You can use [s3 lifecycle polcies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html) to transition objects to Glacier or Deep Archive after some time automatically.

Comment: I see, will do that right now. Also, I was setting up the logs on RDS and was wondering what is the difference between `Postgresql log` and `Upgrade log`. Do you know?

Comment: @NGI I think that the former one is the regular postgresql log, while the latter is generated an upgrade of the db engine is performed.

Comment: I see, does upgrade of the db engine mean, for example, switching from postgres to mysql??

Comment: @NGI Not sure. I think its only for upgrading PostgreSQL itself, e.g. to a new version.